# Chrome thinks a redirected site of mine contains malware

Tags: redirect, malware

Hope someone can help me. :)

I have a main .com site with a number of international top level domains associated with it.

So the .com is the main site that is working fine. 
For some reason the .se site which is a parked domain with a 301 redirect on it gives me a malware error.

Any ideas? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JNr9.png)

I know you can ask for a suspected hacked site to be reviewed as below: 
https://developers.google.com/webmasters/hacked/docs/request_review

But the site isn't associated with any search console account, nor is it a live / active domain.

Any ideas?

Much appreciate any input. :)

Comment: Probaly because of some bad code within your code.

Comment: can you show how the redirection is done?

Comment: the site was bought from a private seller and then moved to safenames.
This problem seems to have crept in a couple of weeks ago, no changes have been made to the code though. 

Although, a number of user permissions have been changed on the main .com site. Might this affect anything? Not to sure that it would but I'm running out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

There may be problems with some scripts in the code lines. Use external script to your site?

Comment: we've just deployed a couple of changes to the site. Maybe something with the cron?

Comment: It's possible, try to revert the changes that you can do.
It sometimes happens that a few changes in the code can be interpreted to the browser a possible malware. You have to see what changes you have made

Comment: It seems that there were changes made both to the cron and js script. Interesting that it was picked up by browser as malware. What would the solution be though?